# Math app with decimal pad crashing

Tags: xcode, swift, math, keyboard, decimal

Hi i´m trying to make a math app with equations i have learned how to get the decimal keyboard but when i use it, it crashes with a message about thread one:

> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
>   The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.
>
> 2016-02-16 21:13:31.682 Formel bok[586:43971] Can't find keyplane that supports type 8 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitChoco-DecimalPad; using 1022227301_PortraitChoco_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default
>
> 2016-02-16 21:13:34.606 Formel bok[586:43971] Can't find keyplane that supports type 8 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitChoco-DecimalPad; using 1022227301_PortraitChoco_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default
>
> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   (lldb) "

But also:

> "Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOIN(code=1,subcode=0x0002a476c)

I believe it does it because its a , not a . dot. I tried setting my phone to american region then i works is there some other solution to make the , work with this code i´m really thankful for any help received.

```html
import UIKit

class CylinderViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var radien: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var höjden: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var svar: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var svar2: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        radien.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.DecimalPad
        höjden.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.DecimalPad
       
        
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)          // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

   
    
    func dismissKeyboard() {
        //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
        view.endEditing(true)
        
        
        
        if höjden.text == ""{
        }
        else{
        
        let atext: Double? = Double(radien.text!)    // conversion of string to Int
        let btext: Double? = Double(höjden.text!)
       
        
        let myInt = atext! * atext!
       
        
        
        let result = Double(myInt * btext!) * M_PI
        svar.text = "\(result)"
        
        
        let pi = M_PI * 2
        
        let result2 = Float(pi) * Float(atext!) * Float(btext!)
        svar2.text = "\(result2)"
        
        
        
        
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Please give us the exact error you are getting

Comment: hi now i have added to error message @KyleRedfearn

Comment: Go to iOS Simulator-> Hardware-> Keyboard -> Uncheck the Connect Hardware Keyboard Option. This will fix the issue.

Comment: If I use your code and as United States I confirm that it works. If I change to Sweden I get nil values for atext and btext.

Comment: same for me, on the iOS simulator it work but i don´t know how to get it working on the iPhone @MwcsMac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your code working to allow for localization. I tried with both US and Sweden and the nil issue is gone.

> **Note:** You will need to do the number formatting on your output as well, but this should help you.

```
import UIKit

class CylinderViewController: UIViewController {
     @IBOutlet weak var radien: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var höjden: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var svar: UILabel!
     @IBOutlet weak var svar2: UILabel!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      radien.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.DecimalPad
      höjden.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.DecimalPad


    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)          // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  }

   func dismissKeyboard() {
       //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
     view.endEditing(true)

    if höjden.text == ""{
    }
    else{

        let nf = NSNumberFormatter() // added to use localization
        let atext = nf.numberFromString(radien.text!) //added
        let btext = nf.numberFromString(höjden.text!) //added
       //let atext: Double? = Double(radien.text!)    // conversion of string to Int
       //let btext: Double? = Double(höjden.text!)

        let myInt = Double(atext!) * Double(atext!)

        let result = Double(myInt * Double(btext!)) * M_PI
        svar.text = "\(result)"

        let pi = M_PI * 2

        let result2 = Float(pi) * Float(atext!) * Float(btext!)
        svar2.text = "\(result2)"

    }

 }

}
```

Comment: Thank you @MwcsMac for your help this solution worked instantly

Answer (score 0):

So you are experiencing several errors. Let start with the one that us causing your crash:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

You are getting this error because you are force unwrapping a nil value. Swift has a nice way of preventing this using the `if let` statement. Try doing this when you create a decimal from a string:

```
if let double: Double? = Double(radien.text) {
    // Use double here
} else {
    // Error handling here
}
```

If Swift can successfully parse your string, you will enter the if statement and you can safely use the `double` variable. If Swift cannot successfully parse your string into a `Double`, it is probably because you have an invalid character in the string and you need to show an error message or something

Comment: thank you asweel for your time and effort your solution worked swell